# Simplifying an expression leads to time out

Tags: timeout, z3, simplify, java

How can I simplify the following expression using Z3 Solver?

```
(declare-const c0 Int)
(declare-const c1 Int)
(declare-const c2 Int)

(assert (let ((a!1 (to_real (+ (* (* 2 c0) c2)
                   (* (* 2 c0) c1)
                   (* 2 c1 c2)
                   (* c0 (- c0 1))
                   (* c1 (- c1 1))))))
  (let ((a!2 (/ (to_real (* (* 2 c0) c2)) a!1)))
  (and (or (and (<= c2 1) (>= c2 1) (<= c0 2) (>= c0 2) (<= c1 3) (>= c1 3))
           (and (<= c2 1) (>= c2 1) (<= c0 3) (>= c0 3) (<= c1 2) (>= c1 2)))
  (= (/ 2.0 15.0) a!2))))
)

(apply (then qe propagate-values (repeat (then ctx-solver-simplify propagate-ineqs) 10)))
```

Link : http://rise4fun.com/Z3/u7F7

I tried all the possible tactics that I know about and yet ended up causing time out by the solver. Is there a way that I can avoid time out? Is it suppose to return false as a result in **Java API**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what's going on just by looking at that code. But I'd think that `to_real` might be the problematic part, as conversion between domains tend to generate non-linear constraints that can cause complexity problems.

I'd give it a try using purely Reals (i.e., declare `c0`, `c1`.. as `Real`s; and remove calls to `to_real`.)

If you do need integers/reals mixed; make sure that mixing is done at the leaves (i.e., at constants); or at the very-top, as much as you can push the conversions around; instead of at intermediate values.

But I'd guess that sticking to Reals would be the way to go here if your problem space allows for that.

Answer (score 1):

The example uses non-linear integer arithmetic. Unfortunately, it is easy to produce examples in this domain where Z3 does not terminate. The ctx-solver-simplify routine calls the SMT solver multiple times and in each invocation has to check satisfiability of some combination of the non-linear constraints.